# How to get the index of active div based on their data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the index of an active div based on their data attributes.

Currently I use the following method to get the index on a sorted table, but this won't work if it is unsorted:

```
var count = $(".active").index();
$( ".count" ).html( count + 1 );

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="data" data-foo="23"></div>
    <div class="data" data-foo="653"></div>
    <div class="data active" data-foo="5"></div>
    <div class="data" data-foo="12"></div>
    <div class="data" data-foo="0"></div>
</div>
<div class="count"></div>
```

Comment: What is your definition of "index" if not jQuery's?

Comment: what about the case, where two or more div elements have same value for 'data-foo', but one is active.
In this case it is not easy to precisely get the correct index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var count = $.inArray($("[data-foo]").filter(".active").data("foo")
              , $.map($("[data-foo]"), function(el, i) {
                  return Number(el.attributes["data-foo"].value)
              }).sort(function(a, b) {
                return a - b
            }));

$(".count").html(count);
```

```js
var count = $.inArray($("[data-foo]").filter(".active").data("foo"), $.map($("[data-foo]"), function(el, i) {
  return Number(el.attributes["data-foo"].value)
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
}));

$(".count").html(count); // +1 ?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="data" data-foo="23"></div>
  <div class="data" data-foo="653"></div>
  <div class="data active" data-foo="5"></div>
  <div class="data" data-foo="12"></div>
  <div class="data" data-foo="0"></div>
</div>
<div class="count"></div>
```